# Python error - AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, pandas, split

Trying to split the data into individual action IDs

```
action_ids_list = [list(map(int, row.split('|'))) for row in data.str.strip().str.split('\n')]
```

data looks like following

```
string_action_ids
10
10|11
10|11|12|13|14|17|18|19|20|22|23|24|25|29|30|38|42|43|44|45|49
10|11|12|13|16|17|18|22|23|24|25|28|29|35|38|41|42|43|45|46|50|54
10|11|12|13|16|22|23|24|25|28|29|35|38|41|42|45|46|50|54
```

I keep getting this error - `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`
how do I resolve this?

Comment: I would guess you are already processing the data but your python is sort of assuming you are dealing with just a string.  What type of object should data be?

Comment: You probably need to be more descriptive here.  Is your goal just a listing of the id's without regard to the sets, keeping them as action sets or perhaps even having a distinct set of actions. I feel like there is not enough clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **replace()** function first to get rid of the '\n' and also have "|" as a delimiter.
This will simplify looping over the split().

```
action_ids_list = [
    int(number) 
    for number in string_action_ids.replace("\n", "|").split("|")
]
```

Comment: I get the following error "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'split'". A bit of a newbie to python

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data is a string on multiple lines, that your don't mind not doing a one-liner, and that you want all your data in a single final list of integers, you can use:

```py
data = """
string_action_ids
10
10|11
10|11|12|13|14|17|18|19|20|22|23|24|25|29|30|38|42|43|44|45|49
10|11|12|13|16|17|18|22|23|24|25|28|29|35|38|41|42|43|45|46|50|54
10|11|12|13|16|22|23|24|25|28|29|35|38|41|42|45|46|50|54
"""

rows = [row for row in data.split("\n")]
action_ids_list = []
for r in rows:
    try:
        action_ids_list += [int(i) for i in r.split("|")]
    except:
        pass

print(action_ids_list)
```